# How to draw multiple images in the canvas in the form of loop?

Tags: jquery, html, image, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw multiple images in the canvas and all the images are coming dynamically. Canvas is showing nothing if I try draw in the form of loop.

```
var pname=getUrlParameter("pname");//getting a string of images
var pname_array = pname.split(",");//converting int the form of array
console.log(pname_array);

$("canvas#c").width("375");//setting width of canvas
var height_canvas = pname_array.length * 554;//total of height of canvas  depends on the number of images (each image height should be 554px)
$("canvas#c").height(height_canvas);

var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

for(var i=0; i < pname_array.length; i++){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = image_get+pname_array[i]+'-sy1';//image source for each iteration
    //image.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage( image, 0, (i*554) );//drawing the image
    //};
}
```

Comment: First I would add one image and see if that works then second . Then I would try looping over all images.

Answer (score 0):

Remove these two lines in the for loop,

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

You've already declared the object outside the loop.

Comment: Please describe more detailed what you've tried already. And from the above comment, can you draw only one image?

Comment: Or maybe you should both add
```canvas.width = 420;
canvas.style.width = 420+"px"
```

Comment: Yes, It always just draw first image in the canvas and ignore the rest of images.

Comment: I think it might be the onload problem, the image loading needs certain time.
```image.load = function() {
    ctx.drawImage();
}
image.error = function() {
    console.log(error);
}```